# Javascript Date.js - slow performance

Tags: javascript, time

im using date.js to parse the following timestamp:

> 04/Jun/2020:08:47:37 +0200

Right now im using substr to gather the first and second part untill the ":". Then i write the string together with a space. My code is below:

```
var timestamp = "04/Jun/2020:08:47:37 +0200";
var splitFitst = timestamp.substr(0, 11); 
var splitSecond = timestamp.substr(12, 25); 
var timeStampFinal = splitFitst + " " + splitSecond;

time = Date.parse(timeStampFinal);
```

It looks like the input timestamp "04/Jun/2020:08:47:37 +0200" slows down my code dramatic.
If I use an iso-timestamp the performance of my code is perfect.

Anyone got an idea how to improve the performance here?
Maybe I have to pass a custom time format?

Comment: How do you measure performance and slowdown?

Comment: i have a tool for which i need time parsing.
It currently processes 500 lines per second (without timestamp).
With the timestamp (the one with the : separated) only about 120 lines per second. 
Otherwise, with an ISO timestamp I don't see any performance penalty.

Comment: Do you need to use date.js? Did you try using the builtin `Date.parse`?